# clrmd - Getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException After using DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, profiling, clrmd

I'm want to get c# object inclusive size by using [clrmd](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd) API.
In order to get this information, first I need to attach to the process. 
To achieve this, I'm using `DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach` method.

For some reason, the application crash after getting `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException` exception with 0x80004005 Error Code

StackTrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.CloseHandle(IntPtr handle)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle.ReleaseHandle()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
```

The root cause for this problem is an exception from the GC Finalizer Thread.

How can I bypass or prevent this exception?

Full code example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

    using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(processId))
    {
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // Will cause exception
}
```

**Update:**
When I "Start Without Debugging", I don't get the exception. But I want to debug.

Comment: I met the similar issue, and for my case, it caused by the Handle was closed more than one time. I fixed it just by keeping the handle only release once. Not sure if the handle is released inside DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(processId).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clrmd fix it and support it from version 1.1.57604.